# Create jQuery array of droppable elements

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, jquery-ui, droppable

I got draggable li - elements and droppable boxes - using jQuery UI.

My structure:

[image]

A list of 3 permission types

```
<ul>
    <li data-action="create">Create</li>
    <li data-action="edit">Edit</li>
    <li data-action="delete">Delete</li>
</ul>
```

And 3 areas to drop:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3>Server</h3>
        <ul class="box" data-type="server"></ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3>Games</h3>
        <ul class="box" data-type="games"></ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h3>User</h3>
        <ul class="box" data-type="user"></ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

I added data-type and data-action attributes for better handling.
My current jQuery code for draggable and droppable:

```
$("#rights > ul > li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});

$("#rights ul.box").droppable({
    activeClass: "helperclass",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<li></li>").html(ui.draggable.text() + '<span class="close">x</span>').appendTo(this);
    }
});

$("#rights").on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).parent().slideUp(200, function() { $(this).remove(); } );
});
```

This works perfect - but now i want to write the data in my MySQL DB.
Perfect would be an array with strings like this:

*server[create], user[edit] etc*

So if submit i think i have to store all dropped elements in an array - but i don't know how to get them (then set it as value of hidden-field):

```
$('#userForm').submit(function() {
    $('#rights .box').each(function() {
        var currentBox = $(this).data('type');
        //Get all data-actions for this box 
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/xw2djxdp/3/

Comment: not entirely clear exactly what data and in what format you want to store in db. Also at what point, after each drop or on user save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
var result = {};
    $('ul.box').each(function () {
        var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
        var elements = [];
        $(this).find('li').each(function () {
            elements.push($(this).text());
        });
        result[type] = elements
    });
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/xw2djxdp/4/

Note: Click on the button and see the results in console